# Exporting datagrid values to excel

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to export values in a datagrid control to excel. The problem I'm having is that after debugging, when I click the button, the application just gets stuck. I cannot close the form either. I have to click the debug button. The excel file also is not created.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item("sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    Next



    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    xlApp = Nothing
    xlWorkBook = Nothing
    xlWorkSheet = Nothing

    MsgBox("You can find the file D:\vbexcel.xlsx")

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? At what point in execution does the program freeze?

Comment: kk....the code actually works.. but it takes a long time... how can i speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
For k As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k + 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(k).HeaderText
Next
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1

        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()

    Next
Next
```

Comment: thanks....it still takes around 10 sec to create the excel  file... can u help me speed it up?

Comment: @user2444712 .. is it work better than yours ? .. because I think this quiet fast for interop work .. or maybe you may try with open your excel as DB connection ..